# carga aleartoria en c con estructura while

Tags: c, codeblocks

debo realizar un ejercicio donde cuento con la estatura de N deportistas, a lo que debo realizar lo siguiente, a) Cargar un arreglo.
b) Indicar cuantos deportistas superan la estatura promedio.

```
#define N 6
float alturapromediototal( int alturapromtot, int arreglo [N])
{
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<N;i++){
        if (arreglo [i]>alturapromtot){
            printf("el deportista %d supera la altura promedio \n",i);
        }

    }
    return 0;
}


int main()
{

    int i,arreglo[N],cantpar;
    float alturapt,alturapromtot,alturaprom;
    alturaprom=0;
    cantpar=0;
    printf("ingrese el numero de participante o -1 para finalizar (entre 1 y 5) :");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    while (i!=-1){
        printf("ingrese la estatura del participante: ");
        scanf("%d",&arreglo[i]);
        alturaprom=alturaprom+arreglo[i];
        cantpar=cantpar+1;
        printf("ingrese el numero de participante o -1 para finalizar (entre 1 y 5) :");
    scanf("%d",&i);

    }
    alturapt=alturaprom/cantpar;
    alturapromediototal (alturapromtot,arreglo);
    printf("la altura promedio es: %d", alturapt);
return 0;

}
```

me tira error, diciendo q la altura promedio es 0 y que siempre el deportista 3 supera la altura promedio, y no se donde puedo tener el error

Comment: Creo que copiaste mal el codigo. Cuando lo pruebo en mi maquina me dice que alturaprom no esta definido.

Comment: ahi realize la edicion, estaba mal copiado perdon

Comment: Gracias, ahorita lo miro

Comment: A la variable `alturapromtot` no le asignas un valor antes de llamar `alturapromediototal`. Creo que omitiste calcularla.